# Asterisk: Saving recording on a another server

Tags: asterisk, phone-call, recording

I want asterisk to save call recording in a folder on a Windows server.
I can't allow any recordings lost while testing because this is a working server,
so I figured I will ask for some general instructions first. 
Also, is it possible to change saving location only for a certain extenstion just for testing?

Asterisk Version: 1.6
FreePbx Version: 2.9

Answer (score 0):

Use samba service connection.

It connect to windows share, posible mount some folder to windows share/folder.

Yes, you can control where to save file in MixMonitor command. Unfortanly for do that you need understand dialplan and linux.